# Gem spree doesn't work in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Gem spree doesn't work in Rails 5

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from <top (required)> at C:/Users/Sergey/spree/config/application.rb:7)
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'spree'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Sergey/spree/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I have added 'spree' gem in Gemfile.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to fix that error

Comment: As far as I know, spree 3.1 supports rails < 4.2.x only

Answer (score 2):

You can use the the bleeding edge version, as follow in the spree's README:

> gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree'
>
> gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise'
>
> gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway'

https://github.com/spree/spree

Answer (score 1):

For now spree is not available for rails 5.0, so if you want to use it, you must go for rails 4.2.6(at least)

Comment: To create a project  using an older version of rails just type:

rails _4.2.6_ new MyAppName

Answer (score 0):

Add Spree gems to your Gemfile:

**Rails 5:**

```
gem 'spree', '~> 3.2.0.rc1'

gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.2.0.beta'

gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.2.0.beta'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ruby 2.4.0 and Rails 5.0.3

Add the gems with the specific version to the Gemfile.

```
gem 'spree', '~> 3.2.0' 
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.2.0.beta' 
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.2.0.beta'
```

After that try to install the following generators to set up Spree:

```
rails g spree:install --user_class=Spree::User
rails g spree:auth:install
rails g spree_gateway:install
```

It is working for me. Let me know any issues.